# problem debugging with conditional breakpoint python

Tags: python, debugging, conditional-breakpoint

When I try to run the following bit of code, I get the error `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()` (referring to the variable `stringConverted`).  I've tested different values and it works for the ones I've tested.  I was thinking that the best way to debug this is to figure out what value of `i` causes a 'NoneType'.  So I tried to set a conditional breakpoint where `stringConverted = 'NoneType'` so that when I run it, the program should stop when this condition is true.  But when I try to run it after setting the conditional break point, it just runs all the way through producing the same error.  what am I doing wrong here?  Is the way I formatted my conditional breakpoint statement correct?

```
def main():
    totalChars = 0
    for i in range(1,500):
        stringConverted = stringConvert(i)
        totalChars = totalChars + len(stringConverted)
    print totalChars
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    totalChars = 0
    for i in range(1,500):
        stringConverted = stringConvert(i)
        if stringConverted is None:
            print i
            break
        totalChars = totalChars + len(stringConverted)
    else:
        print "No error!"
    print totalChars
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `if stringConverted is None` instead of checking the type to see if it is `NoneType`.

Comment: Correct. ...and he's not even checking the `type` - he's actually comparing it directly to the string `NoneType'

Comment: @F.J. that makes sense but for some reason it still doesn't work.  Does this depend on the IDE at all?

Comment: @sq1020 - Post your code with the breakpoint in it, this method should work on all versions of Python on any system.